# Algorithm to find the difference between adjacent elements whose difference is closer to zero

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is an sorted  array of n elements (both positive and negative)  we have to  find the difference between each pair of elements are (adjacent ) difference between elements with indices  (0  1, 1  2, 2  3 and so on n-1 n )and find which difference is close to zero.

Ex: -56 -57 -46 -43 -33 -25 -24 -12 -10  1 3 6 7 8 9 56 57 68 78

Here 1 is the difference closer to 0.

Condition: without finding the difference between each and every pair don't traverse the entire array

I have got it but without the condition

Comment: if you just compare 0-1, 1-2, 2-3 and so on you already don't compare all pairs (such as 0-2, 0-3 and so on). Show your code, it's probably already correct.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the pairs in a linear fashion by accessing them with indices `i` and `i + 1`:

```
best = ABS(data[0] - data[1]);
for (i = 1; i < data.length - 2; i++)
{
    d = ABS(data[i] - data[i + 1]);
    if (d < best)
    {
        best = d;
    }
}
```

You may want to break out of the `for()` early, but it depends. It has a cost.

```
    if (best == 0)
    {
        break; // for()
    }
```